# My blueberry bush was isn’t growing

Tags: shrubs

My blueberry bush hasn’t grown since we got it… unfortunately it was accidentally trimmed down and we are worried he won’t grow… his root ball is very small and we would appreciate help.

Comment: Can you add more detail please such as where you are in the world, when  you got the plant, when was it cut down, is it in the ground or in a pot? A photo might also be useful...

Comment: Soil pH is also important , blueberries like acid.